# Gitlab CI Runner: FATAL: Command sh not found

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I tried to configure a gitlab-runner.
This is the tutorial I used: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html
The steps were no problem, but when I actually ran the Runner it stops with the error below. The only online resource referencing this problem is this one: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1762
But I can't see a solution in there.

The Gitlab Version is: 10.4.3

Output of the Runner:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.7.2 (b5e03c94)
  on Runner for .NET Core 2 0945b842
Using Docker executor with image gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest ...
Pulling docker image gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:abe39c16d28c87fefad753d02a89f8764a7577439a4851ec1f7d5228df69e48e for gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest ...
Running on runner-0945b842-project-66-concurrent-0 via 32359ca86797...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at b180fbf -
From https://<redacted>
   b180fbf..3acaee5  <redacted> -> origin/<redacted>
Checking out 3acaee5f as <redacted>...
Skipping Git submodules setup
FATAL: Command sh not found.                       
FATAL: Command sh not found.                       
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

The `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variables:
  GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY: "1"

before_script:
  - docker login <redacted>

runnertest:
  tags:
    - dotnet
  script:
    - echo 'test'
```

The `config.toml`:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "Runner for .NET Core 2"
  url = "<redacted>"
  token = "0945b84283ca87d541418edb23bc8c"
  executor = "docker"
  tls_verify = false
  [runners.docker]
    environment = ['GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true']
    image = "gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

Comment: Does .net have echo command?

Comment: Uhm, no I don't think so. But isn't "dotnet" just a tag here for runner selection? edit: dotnet isn't even installed on the docker-image yet since I just use the default gitlab/gitlab-runner image for testing.